# How do I convert a list of paired arrays into 2x1 arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, encryption

I am trying to write a Hill Cipher program in Python that allows the user to input their own 2x2 matrix and message to be encoded or decoded.
The Message "Hello World" has been enciphered into the following list:

```
Num_Msg= [array([-24,   5]), array([12, 12]), array([ 15, -64]), array([-9, 15]), array([18, 12]), array([  4, -64])]
```

Now I want to take each of those arrays and convert them to 2x1 vector in order to np.dot by the 2x2 matrix key. The coding

```
for i in Num_Msg:

        Vector=[np.ndarray(Num_Msg[i],shape=(2,1))]
        Dot_Product=np.dot(Vector,Key_Matrix)
```

results in

> TypeError: only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an
>   index.

I have similarly tried `np.reshape (Num_Msg,(2,1))` to similar results. Any help on this project would be great

Comment: the 1st `i` in `for i in Num_Msg:` is `array([-24, 5])`  `i` is not an index,it is  the actual element

Comment: I see, how do I make it the index? I should mention my knowledge of coding is extremely minimal. thank you

Comment: `for i in range(len(Num_Msg))` is considered crude, there is `enumerate`, but "pythonic" is to just operate on the returned elment, no need to reindex into the list

Comment: for i in range(len(Num_Msg)):
          Msg_Vectors=np.reshape(Num_Msg[i], (2,1))    results in message    ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are seeing is that `i` already is your vector. So the loop you are looking for is

```
for Vector in Num_Msg:   # Notice Vector is the variable we're iterating over
    Dot_Product=np.dot(Vector, Key_Matrix)
```

After cleaning it all up you would end up with

```
Num_Msg = np.array([[-24, 5], [12, 12], [15, -64], [-9, 15], [18, 12], [4, -64]])
Key_Matrix = numpy.random.rand(2, 2)

Dot_Product = numpy.array([np.dot(V, Key_Matrix) for V in Num_Msg])
```

However, there is no need for the for loop but you can let `numpy.einsum` do the loop for you:

```
Dot_Product2 = numpy.einsum('fi,ij->fj', Num_Msg, Key_Matrix)
```

And to make sure the two actually yield the same results:

```
numpy.allclose(Dot_Product, Dot_Product2)    # True
```

Comment: @DanielArevalo Don't forget to hit the all important accept V mark to the left of the answer if this fully answers your question.

Comment: The checkmark next to my post to mark it as a valid answer.